# Integrate drupal & moodle

Tags: drupal, single-sign-on, moodle

I need to integrate two CMS i.e. Drupal and Moodle. Initially my requirement is Single sign on process.

Both the sites have their own different database and they don't share common user table. I started using Drupal CAS module but I am stuck with the configuration of drupal side as well as on moodle site.

Please help me.

> Drupal site:  [www.jenegocios.com](http://www.jenegocios.com)
>
> Moodle Site:  [www.moodle.jenegocios.com](http://www.moodle.jenegocios.com)

Comment: First you need to install Moodle and drupal in the server. There is authentication plugin available moodle-drupalservices for SSO between both systems.

Comment: I used Services module for drupal 7 which provide SSO settings and also used drupalservices for moodle, but I am getting error on moodle side:<br/> Fail : cookies: SSO Cookie not discovered. 1) check that you are currently logged in to drupal. 2) Check that Drupal's session cookie is configured in settings.php 3) check that cookie_domain is properly filled in.
Fail : system/connect: User session data reachable but you aren't logged in!
Fail : muser/Index: An authentication error occurred